# How to dynamically add users on the page using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im having some trouble figuring this out. I have a database which has users on it and I want to display each user on the page dynamically using jquery.

Ive just thrown some user data objects in a array and im trying to call for each user object in the array to display as a list item on the page

html

```
<h1>List</h1>
<ul id="list">

</ul>
```

javascript

```
var user = [
{
    username: alex,
    age: 20
},
{
    username: james,
    age: 20
}
]

function addUser() {
    var username = user.username;
    var age = user.age

    var $user = $("<li>" + username + "</li>");
    var $age = $("<li>" + age + "</li>");

    $("#list").append($user + " " + $age);
}

$.each(user, addUser());
```

Comment: change addUser() to addUser

Comment: Hey I gave that a try but the users still dont show up in the <ul> any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please check page: https://jsfiddle.net/rxcz73x9/2/

```
var user = [{
   username: "alex", // use string
   age: 20
}, {
   username: "james", // use string
   age: 20
}];

function addUser(idx, user) {
   var username = user.username;
   var age = user.age

   var $user = $("<li>" + username + "</li>");
   var $age = $("<li>" + age + "</li>");

   $("#list").append($user).append($age); // use append for each node
}

$.each(user, addUser); // use function name instead of addUser()
```

I've added comment that could help you with example above.

Comment: Great thanks this works! but can you please tell me where you got idx from and why do you need it in addUser(idx, user)?? thanks a lot

Comment: That's part of the specification for the .each() function.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is very simple. You have to replace `addUser()` by `addUser` when you use the `$.each` method. There are also mistakes when you use the`.append` method. Try this code:

```js
var user = [
    {
      username: "alex",
      age: 20
    },
    {
      username: "james",
      age: 20
    }
  ];
  function addUser(theCase, value) {
    var username = value.username;
    var age = value.age;

    
    var user = '<li> ' + username;  // Use a simple string, it's better and faster!
    var age = age + ' </li>';

    $("#list").append(user + " " + age);
  }

  $.each(user, addUser);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>List</h1>
  <ul id="list">

</ul>
```

Here you are using a callback. If you want more details about callbacks consult the [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

There are also several errors on [`.each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method or [`.append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method. Consult the documentation.

The `.each` method call your callback for each case on your array `user`. This method also provide you, in your callback, the index and the value of the case witch is treated.

Comment: I tried this and the users still don't show up in the <ul> any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a callback to the jQuery `each` function, what happens is that the callback is going to be invoked with every element in your `user` array.

Check the arguments that [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) passes to the callback. The callback function signature should expect the index and the value of the element in that index.

For example:

```
var users = user = [
  {
    username: alex,
    age: 20
  },
  {
    username: james,
    age: 20
  }
];

function addUser(index, user) {
  // do what you want and in the end
  $('#list').append(/* an <li> element */);
};

// Now pass the function as a callback, but don't invoke it.
$.each(users, addUser);
```

Comment: Hey there thanks for responding im not quite sure where you are getting the addUser(index, user) from? thanks

Comment: Check the documentation in the [link I provided](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/). `jQuery.each` passes these arguments to the callback function: `( Integer indexInArray, Object value )`. Take a look at the examples and I'm sure it will all make sense. Remember, functions in javascript are first-class citizens, meaning that they can be passed around and used like any other variable ;). Their strength is that they can be called, and that's the trick used here.

Comment: lightbulb moment! Thanks! been having trouble wrapping my head around it!